# Difference in Actual mysql query output and JSON output

Tags: php, mysql

My below code gives JSON output but the amount value is very high. On the other hand when i execute the mysql query separately, amount value is current.

Is the php function creating an erroneous value?

```
<?php
 $DB_NAME = 'mro';
 $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DB_USER = 'mysql';
 $DB_PASS = 'sql';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
$query = "select a.obook as code,sum(a.amt) as Amount from mtrans a where orgdate between '20131001' and '20131031' and a.obook <> '1' group by a.obook";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    {
    $rows = array();
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
            array('label' => 'Book', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'Amount', 'type' => 'number')
    );

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $temp = array();
            $temp[] = array('v' => "Store books");
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Amount']);
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
            }
   }
 }

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: Its JSON, not JASON.

Comment: you're sure that the exact same query run against the exact same database returns different values?

Comment: yes the same on mysql prompt it gives 13120362199.51 but in JSON output it gives 2147483647 i am very confused how that can be

Comment: You're converting the "Amount" to int and you have very large values. It is possible that you run into an integer overflow.

Comment: yes Thomas you were correct thanks